# Best java tools for emacs

Tags: java, debugging, emacs, ide, javadoc

I'm a long-time emacs user, and I'm now working about 1/2 time in Java.

What are the best emacs libraries for

1. Debugging Java
2. Code Completion/Intellisense
3. Javadoc browsing

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) on several projects.  It handles Code Completion.  I've never used it for debugging or browsing docs, but it's a big step up from a basic text editor.

Answer (score 4):

For javadoc I found http://javadochelp.sourceforge.net/index.html to be the best.

Exuberant ctags is your best friend when it comes to navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with [jdibug](http://code.google.com/p/jdibug/) for debugging Java code with Emacs.