# Working with Java from Emacs within Leiningen project

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, leiningen

There's plenty of closely related questions on SO, just to name some of them:

- [Java and Clojure with Leiningen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432163/java-and-clojure-with-leiningen)
- [What is the best way to do Java development in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156529/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-java-development-in-emacs)
- [Best java tools for emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056/best-java-tools-for-emacs)

The difference of my questions is that I want to know how to make working **with Java as easy as with Clojure** right from **Emacs** within mixed Clojure/Java Leiningen project.

What I mean is possibility to (in order of priority):

- **compile** Java code right from Emacs (note: it is possible to compile it from the shell with `lein javac`)
- use **code completion** for Java (tools like [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) provide this feature, but it is separate tool that doesn't concern Leiningen project setup)
- **debug** Java code

Comment: JDEE is your best option if you really want to do the Java work in Emacs. IMO not worth it, but it's adequate.

Comment: For intellient completion you can try [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which also has an emacs interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Emacs LSP project](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode). It provides support for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I want to try [auto complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) but I haven't gotten to it yet.

Given the way leiningen/Clojure work anyway, I'm not sure how easy you could make compilation. When you compile Java code, don't you have to restart the repl/application for the JVM to reload it anyway?

Comment: Actually, it is possible to reload class from running Java process using custom ClassLoader (see [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)). However, I'm not switching between Java and Clojure too frequently, so it is ok for me to restart slime-clojure from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

[Malabar-mode](https://github.com/espenhw/malabar-mode) is abandonware but I think it's shooting for the level of functionality that you want. It seems to me that a coprocess-based autocompletion engine should be feasible with CEDET, leiningen, and swank-clojure, but I have a day job and side work...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you wanted exactly, but this should handle bullet 1 for ya:

```lisp
(defun lein-javac (&optional PROJECT-DIR)
  (interactive)
  (let ((output-buffer (progn
                         (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*lein-javac*" nil )
                         (select-window (get-buffer-window "*lein-javac*"))
                         (read-only-mode 'toggle)
                         (window-buffer)) ))
   (shell-command (concat "cd " (or PROJECT-DIR default-directory) 
                         " && lein javac &") "*lein-javac*")))
```